# Prohibition of purchase for non login users for magento 2

Tags: magento2

I know there's a way to make this prohibition in magento 1 but what about magento 2? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find that parameter here, in backoffice

> Stores > Configuration > Sales > Checkout > Checkout Options > Allow Guest Checkout > No